# Android AsyncTask called from fragment none of its members called - doInbackground, onpreexecute, onpostexecute

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-fragmentactivity

I am trying to read a uri which returns either a 0 or -1.
The asynctask is called from inside a Fragment.
Basically, its a login when the user clicks a button the inputs are checked on the remote server.

## In the debugger the task shows as RUNNING but never completes, also none of the overridden member are called, which may explain why it does nothing.

The Login Code is :

```
// Validate the user.
    String uri = HLConsts.SERV_URI + "ValidateLoginUser?uname=" + szUserName + "&password=" + szPassword + "&android=1";
    ReadUri rd = new ReadUri(uri);
    int cnt =0;
    rd.execute();
    while ( rd.getSzReturn() == null  || cnt > 5) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        cnt++;
    }
    if(cnt > 5) {
        errors++;
    }

    String szValid = rd.getSzReturn();

        Snackbar.make(root, "Name = " + szUserName + " Pass = " + szPassword , Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
            .setAction("Action", null).show();
```

============================
The Async Task is :

```
public class ReadUri  extends AsyncTask< Void , Void, String> {
 //   private Context mContext;
    private String mUrl;
    private String szReturn = null;



    public String getSzReturn() {
        return szReturn;
    }

    public ReadUri(  String url) {
      //  mContext = context;
        mUrl = url;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();


     //   dynamictext = (TextView)   myView.findViewById(R.id.textview_first);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String resultString = null;
        resultString = getString(mUrl);

        return resultString;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String strings) {
        super.onPostExecute(strings);
        szReturn =strings;
    }


    //======================================================================================
    private String getString(String InUrl) {

        String ret = "Nothing";


        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(InUrl);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
        try {
            httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // The line below is where the exception is called
        int response = 0;
        try {
            response = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.i("Response", String.valueOf(response));

        if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            // Response successful
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            try {
                inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Parse it line by line
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line;
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            while (true) {
                try {
                    //             if (!((temp = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)) {
                    while((line=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)
                    {
                        //   sb.append(line);      //appends line to string buffer
                        //   sb.append("\n");     //line feed
                        ret += line;
                        Log.w("MyApp",line);
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                // Parsing of data here

            }
        } else {
            Log.e("SAMES", "INCORRECT RETURN CODE: " + response);
        }

        httpURLConnection.disconnect();

        //  urlConnection.disconnect();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Please would you help.  I have set breakpoints and none of them are triggered and doInBackground is never called.

Thanks
Jeff.

Comment: `rd.execute();` Remove all code lines after that statement. Handle the result in onPostExecute.

Comment: `|| cnt > 5)` I think you ment `|| cnt < 5)`. But anyhow that was bad coding. Follow my first comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed by not using an external class to run the asynctask.

The example is below :
[AsyncTask Android example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example)